# Overlapping cookies for subdomain

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using JS Cookie library (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

I've configured my development environment to serve my website locally on dev subdomain.

So my live website url is `example.com` and development version runned localy is `dev.example.com`

Also I've implemented subdomains for different language versions of my website. So live url looks like this: `lang.example.com` and dev looks like this: `lang.dev.example.com`

I'm setting cookie every time user change website language. So user can visit default url `example.com` and choose language XY. Then they'll be redirected to xy.example.com and cookie lang: xy will be set.

Why I'm setting cookie in addition to subdomain indicator of current language? Because when user visit again example.com I want to redirect them to xy.website.com because this is the language which they chose last time.

It's working pretty well with one exception.

Those language cookies overlap on my development environment. It means when I set language XY on my live website, that cookie takes precedence over my dev website.

I have following cookies set in my browser:

```
name    value    domain
lang    xy       .dev.example.com
lang    qw       .example.com
```

Whenever I want to test language settings on my dev environment I need to delete my live website cookie `.website.com` because it overlaps the one set for `.dev.example.com`

By that I mean when I want to get lang cookie value on my `dev.website.com` I receive `qw` value instead of `xy` value.

Is there any solution to overcome this problem or I need to clear cookies every time?

Comment: Perhaps use localStorage instead?

Comment: @JeremyHarris localStorage won't work because they don't support cross domain. When someone will change lang on example.com, localStorage with that lang will be set. So example.com will store lang X. When someone will change lang on x.example.com it won't change previously stored lang value at example.com thus they will be always redirected from example.com to x.example.com without possibility to change back the lang.